# Global numeric Constant in python

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to define numeric constant value in python(global constant). Eg. If I define S_max = 80. then this can be changed but I want if its once declared it cannot be changed

Comment: pconst library would be helpful : https://github.com/simon-ritchie/pconst

Answer (score 0):

Try to make some function which return some numeric like:

```
def my_constant():
    num = 80 
    return num
```